# Transformation of Minkowski vectors by group action on Hilbert spaces

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, group-representations

I tried searching for an answer to this, but I suppose I'm using wrong search strings.

Let $a^{\mu}$ be a vector (of real numbers) in Minkowski spacetime. On a Hilbert space, let $U(\Lambda)$ denote a unitary representation of the Lorentz group. Let $A^\mu$ be a vector of operators in the Hilbert space; in other words:

$$
U^{-1}(\Lambda)A^\mu U(\Lambda) = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\;\nu}A^\nu.
$$

My question is: **does the following equation hold?**

$$
U^{-1}(\Lambda)a^\mu U(\Lambda) = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\;\nu}a^\nu
$$

Edit: **If not, can you provide an explanation for the examples given below?**

On the one hand, by definition the representation $U$ acts on vectors and, by extension, on operators of the Hilbert space. So the answer would appear to be: no. On the other hand, $U^{-1} \cdot U$ is meant to signify a Lorentz transformation. So: yes?

**

I will give three examples.

1) Consider the operator $a_\mu A^\mu$; this should be Lorentz invariant and thus, by inserting the identity $UU^{-1}$:

$$
a_\mu A^\mu = U^{-1}(\Lambda)a_\mu A^\mu U(\Lambda) = U^{-1}(\Lambda)a_\mu U(\Lambda) U^{-1}(\Lambda)A^\mu U(\Lambda) = U^{-1}(\Lambda)a_\mu U(\Lambda) \Lambda^\mu _{\;\nu} A^\nu.
$$

This implies

$$
U^{-1}(\Lambda)a_\mu U(\Lambda) = \Lambda_\mu ^{\;\nu} a_\nu,
$$

(*) at least when $a^{\mu}$ is combined with an operator.

2) For an element $(\Lambda,a)$ of the Poincaré group, we know the generators $M^{\mu\nu}$ of the Lorentz subgroup transform as

$$
U^{-1}(\Lambda,a) M^{\mu\nu} U(\Lambda,a) = \Lambda^\mu _{\;\rho} \Lambda^\nu _{\;\sigma} (M^{\rho \sigma} + a^\rho P^\sigma - a^\sigma P^\sigma),
$$

where $P^\mu$ are the generators of translations. Since

$$
(\Lambda,a) = (1,a)(\Lambda,0) \implies U(\Lambda,a)=U(1,a)U(\Lambda,0) \equiv U(a)U(\Lambda)
$$

and

$$
U^{-1}(a) M^{\mu\nu} U(a) = M^{\mu\nu} + a^\mu P^\nu - a^\nu P^\mu
$$

we must have

$$
U^{-1}(\Lambda) a^\mu P^\nu U(\Lambda) = \Lambda^\mu _{\;\rho} \Lambda^\nu _{\;\sigma} a^\rho P^\sigma.
$$

Thus, we reach the same conclusion, possibly with the same caveat (*).

3) If $U(\Lambda)a^\mu = a^\mu U(\Lambda)$ then (with notation as defined below)

$$
U(\Lambda) P^\mu \Psi_p = U(\Lambda) p^\mu \Psi_p = p^\mu U(\Lambda) \Psi_p,
$$

which is clearly not true.

**

My motivation for asking this was the following. Let $\Psi_p$ be an eigenvector of the momentum operator $P$:

$$
P^\mu \Psi_p = p^\mu \Psi_p.
$$

Then, the following holds

$$
P^\mu U(\Lambda) \Psi_p = U(\Lambda) U^{-1}(\Lambda) P^\mu U(\Lambda) \Psi_p = U(\Lambda) \Lambda^{\mu}_{\;\nu} p^\nu \Psi_p = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\;\nu} p^\nu U(\Lambda) \Psi_p.
$$

I have no issue with the content of the equation above. However, given the transformation properties of Minkowski vectors under $U$ as stated, I don't think one can just perform the last step in the equation above without any justification?

Consider the following example, contrived as it may be. In the penultimate step above, insert back $U^{-1}U$

$$
U(\Lambda) \Lambda^{\mu}_{\;\nu} p^\nu \Psi_p = U(\Lambda) \Lambda^{\mu}_{\;\nu} p^\nu U^{-1}(\Lambda) U(\Lambda) \Psi_p, 
$$

and thus, if the above transformation law of Minkowski vectors holds, we obtain

$$
P^\mu U(\Lambda) \Psi_p = (\Lambda^{-1})^\mu _{\;\rho} \Lambda^{\rho}_{\;\nu} p^\nu U(\Lambda) \Psi_p = p^\mu U(\Lambda) \Psi_p,
$$

which is clearly not true. Perhaps (*) applies?

What am I missing? It seems clear to me that $U(\Lambda)$ at least carries an implicit Lorentz transformation of Minkowski space. In general, I have a hard time wrapping my head around inserting $U U^{-1}=U^{-1}U$ because it mixes the passive and active views, in a sense.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is that a straight up vector is in a sense not Lorentz covariant, because it picks out a preferred direction in spacetime: its own. At least I have no doubt that the answer to your question in bold is: no, it doesn't, because $a^\mu$ is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: The question makes little sense to me. If $a\in\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$ is just a vector in Minkowski space and $U(\Lambda)$ a unitary operator on a Hilbert space, then what does writing $U^{-1}(\Lambda)a U(\Lambda)$ even *mean*? There is no obvious notion of multiplying together a vector in Minkowski space and an operator, the operation is simply *undefined*.

Comment: I may have caused confusion by stating that $a^\mu$ is a Minkowski vector. Of course, what I meant (and what I think is fairly common abuse of notation), is that $a^\mu$ are the components of a Minkowski vector, and thus transform in the well-defined manner under a Lorentz transformation. At the very least, $a^\mu$ are just numbers, so $U^{-1}a^\mu U$ is indeed defined. My supposition, though, is that their vectorial character also plays some role here, which is not quite clear to me, and separates them from mere scalars.

Answer (score 3):

No. The second equation is incorrect. The $a^\mu$ are numbers, i.e  elements of the field over which the Hilbert space is defined. The $U(\Lambda)$ are linear opertors on the Hilbert space ---  so $U(\Lambda) a^\mu= a^\mu U(\Lambda)$ by the definition of linearity.

Let me add another comment that might help:  Consider your equation
$$
U^{-1}(\Lambda) A^\mu U(\Lambda)= {\Lambda^{\mu}}_\nu A^\nu
$$ and ask how we are to get the representation property. $U(\Lambda_2\Lambda_1)=U(\Lambda_2)U(\Lambda_1)$. We have 
$$
U^{-1}(\Lambda_1)[U^{-1}(\Lambda_2)A^\mu U(\Lambda_2)] U(\Lambda_1)
= U^{-1}(\Lambda_1)[{(\Lambda_2)^\mu}_\nu A^\nu] U(\Lambda_2)=
{(\Lambda_2)^\mu}_\nu [U^{-1}(\Lambda_1)A^\nu U(\Lambda_1)]=
{(\Lambda_2)^\mu}_\nu {(\Lambda_1)^\nu}_\lambda A^\lambda.
$$
where we have takes the numbers ${(\Lambda_2)^\mu}_\nu$ through the operator $U^{-1}(\Lambda_1)$. If $\Lambda\mapsto U(\Lambda)$ is a representation, this must  equal
$$
U^{-1}(\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1)A^\mu U(\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1)= (\Lambda_2 {\Lambda_1)^\mu}_\lambda A^\lambda.
$$
We see that it does because ${(\Lambda_2)^\mu}_\nu {(\Lambda_1)^\nu}_\lambda= {(\Lambda_2\Lambda_1)^\mu}_\lambda$.  The matrix product  ${(\Lambda_2)^\mu}_\nu$ and ${(\Lambda_1)^\nu}_\lambda$ would be in the wrong order if the numbers ${(\Lambda_2)^\mu}_\nu$ constituting the entries in the matrix representing the Lorentz transformation  in four dimensional Minkowski space   did not pass through the operator $U$ representing the Lorentz transformation in the infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: That explanation makes sense. Although, I have to admit I have never seen it explicitly stated that the Hilbert space is a space over Minkowski "field" (or $\mathbb{R}^3$ in QM). Still, the Lorentz transformation of $a^\mu$ must be implicit, at least? As my two examples would suggest.

Comment: I have edited my original question in response to your answer.

Comment: @noos:The Hilbert space is over ${\mathbb C}$. The entries in $a^\mu$ are real numbers, butare  still in  ${\mathbb C}$.  That they are components of a Minkowski vector is irrelevent. The  components of any vector are still numbers.

Comment: @noos: I expanded my answer to address the representation property.

Comment: Thank you for expanding. I have, of course, completely misunderstood your comment regarding the field. As for your example, I don't think it addresses the issue: the elements of $\Lambda_2$ do not constitute a tensor in Minkowski space; $\Lambda$ maps between reference frames. Indeed, here $(\Lambda_2)^\mu _{\;\nu}$ could be interpreted as just numbers, forming a linear combination with the $A^\nu$s. The issue for me is how a quantity with well defined transformation properties under a Lorentz transformation changes between $U^{-1} U$, which implies said transformation.